# Helm inheriting variable value

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

consider this values.yaml file and secrets.yaml fle.
Is there  any way to read `prometheus.promethesSpec.thanos.objectStorageConfig.name` and
pass the data of the variable `thanosObjectStoreConfig` (which is the value of above dict) to the secrets.yaml ?

**values.yaml**

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    thanos:
      image: thanosio/thanos:v0.11.0
      objectStorageConfig:
        name: thanosObjectStoreConfig
        key: storage

# Defining storage configs for thanos
thanosObjectStoreConfig:
  type: AZURE
  config:
    storage_account: "xxxxxxx"
    storage_account_key: "xxxxxxxxx"
    container: "prometheus"
    endpoint: "blob.core.windows.net"
    max_retries: 0
```

**secrets.yaml**

```
{{- if .Values.prometheus.prometheusSpec.thanos }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: thanos-object-store-config
type: Opaque
data:
  storage: < should contain values of `thanosObjectStorageConfig` | b64enc >
  # Tried not working as expected
  # storage: {{ tpl .Values.prometheus.prometheusSpec.thanos.objectStorageConfig.name $ }}
{{ end }}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to avoid the problem entirely.  When you `helm install` or `helm upgrade` a chart, you can provide any number of `-f` options to specify additional YAML values files.  You can put the specific storage configuration (what you have under the `thanosObjectStoreConfig` top-level key) in a separate file, with a fixed top-level key, and `helm install -f` with different files in different environments.

```
helm install -f values-production.yaml ...
```

If you really want to switch this based on a key, the core Go [text/template](https://godoc.org/text/template) language includes an `index` function that can do a dynamic lookup:

```
{{- $key := .Values.prometheus.prometheusSpec.thanos.objectStorageConfig.name }}
data:
  storage: {{ index .Values $key | toYaml | b64enc }}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. One more doubt. Is it possible to `{{ toYaml <dict> }}` without a child node ?

Comment: I think you can give pretty much any value to `toYaml` and get a string back.